# Criar variável no R, de acordo com variáveis anteriores

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, variáveis

(R) Gostaria de criar uma variável nova, de acordo com outras anteriores.

Tenho informação que os pacientes tomam 4 medicações, mas preciso criar mais uma em formato dummy indicando apenas se ele toma alguma medicação ou não.

```
medicacao1    medicacao2    medicacao3    medicacao4    medicacao
    1             0             0             1             1
    0             0             0             0             0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa usando `tidyverse`. A ideia é checar se alguma das colunas por linha é maior que 0.

#### Código

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <-
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(medicamento = 1*any(c_across(cols = everything()) > 0))
```

Comment: Você poderia me ajudar a salvar este resultado em uma variável?

Comment: Claro, é só usar o operador `<-` que faz a atribuição a um objetivo, então você define o nome da variável a esquerda e sua operação/valor a direita, e.g., `x <- 2+3`. Logo, para o meu código acima fiz uma atualização salvando em um objeto chamado `df2`, porém também poderia sobrescrever o `data.frame ` `df`

Answer (score 2):

Para ver se algum (`any`) dos valores é igual a 1, basta um `apply`.

```r
apply(dados, 1, any)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Agora é só converter para numérico e criar a nova coluna.

```r
dados$medicacao <- as.integer(apply(dados, 1, any))
dados
#>   medicacao1 medicacao2 medicacao3 medicacao4 medicacao
#> 1          1          0          0          1         1
#> 2          0          0          0          0         0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Outra maneira é verificar se as somas em cada linha são maiores que 0. A função `rowSums` é bastante mais rápida que `apply`.

```r
dados$medicacao <- as.integer(rowSums(dados) > 0)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Dados

```r
dados <- "medicacao1    medicacao2    medicacao3    medicacao4    medicacao
    1             0             0             1             1
    0             0             0             0             0"
dados <- read.table(textConnection(dados), header = TRUE)[-5]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `rowSums` e testar se a soma é maior que zero. Veja abaixo.

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
> df <- as.data.frame(list(medicamento1=c(1,0), medicamento2=c(0,0), medicamento3=c(0,0), medicamento4=c(1,0)))
> df
  medicamento1 medicamento2 medicamento3 medicamento4
1            1            0            0            1
2            0            0            0            0
```

### Criando nova coluna com mutate.

```
> df <- df %>% mutate(medicamento = ifelse(rowSums(.[,c(-1)]) > 0, 1, 0))
> df
  medicamento1 medicamento2 medicamento3 medicamento4 medicamento
1            1            0            0            1           1
2            0            0            0            0           0
```